# Assigning incremental file names

Tags: python

I need to search for some string in a files and copy the content in between to a separate file.

For e.g. 'Hello' is repeated multiple times in a file. I want to copy text between these subsequent 'Hello' to a file. Everytime a 'Hello' repeats the text following it needs to go to a new file.

Please confirm if my logic used in following script is correct and also its giving me indentation error from my 'If' loop.

```
import re

text_file = "Hello.txt"
search1 = "Hello"
outfile = "charlie"
write1 = False
x = 0

with open(text_file , "r") as infile:
    fi = infile.readlines()
with open("outfile%s" % x, "w") as fo:
    fo.write("============================================ \n")
    for line in fi:
        if search1 in line:
            write1 = True
            x +=1
            fo.write(line)
        elif write1:
            fo.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
text_file = 'Hello.txt'
search_key = 'Hello'
out_file = 'charlie_%d.txt'
current_file = None
occurrence = 0

with open(text_file, 'r') as input_file:
    try:
        for src_line in input_file:
            if search_key in src_line:
                # searched text is found, writing to file
                occurrence += 1
                if current_file:
                    current_file.close()
                current_file = open(out_file % occurrence, 'w')
                current_file.write("============================================ \n")
                current_file.write(src_line)
            elif current_file:
                # no searched text, write line to already open file
                current_file.write(src_line)
    finally:
        if current_file:
            current_file.close()
```

Comment: I tried above, however its still giving me indentation error after 'If' loop.  I reformatted the script several times however this error is consistent

Comment: occurrence += 1
         ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: I am using Pycharm   ..... I just tried copying and pasting exact text you pasted and it worked somehow ( No idea still about whats the error in my code as pasted above)  .... still I am not able to achieve what I wanted to.

Comment: with open(text_file, 'r') as input_file:
        for src_line in input_file:
            if search_key in src_line:
                # searched text is found, writing to file
                occurrence += 1
                with open(out_file % occurrence, 'w') as output_file:
                       output_file.write("============================================ \n")
                output_file.write(src_line)
        elif write1:
            fo.write(src_line)
            print("hello")

Comment: With this code it just printa the line where matching text is found and doesn't go to next "elif" to print other text

Comment: Error in the code is that for indentation tabs and spaces are used. Only one of them is allowed in python.

Comment: I typed the script again and this time it didn't give that error.                    However when it goes to 'elif' the output file is already closed. Hence Its only able to write the line where it finds the match. However I want to write subsequent lines as well to that file as mentioned in my description

Comment: Got it working now .... used the following  --------------- with open(text_file , 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if search1 in line:
            write1 = True
            x += 1
            fo = open(outfile % x , 'w')
            fo.write(line)
            print("hello1")
        elif write1:
            fo.write(line)

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Comment: I updated the code in my answer, before I did not fully understand your question, now lines between matched lines are written to the `current_file`.